# cmbright for text and math with fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode

Simply put, I would like to use CM Bright for my entire document, but the math remains in Computer Modern Roman, it seems. I *can* get the font set up to work by mixing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{cmbright}` and only declaring a main font, but something tells me it's a bad idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{CMU Bright}
\setmainfont{CMU Bright}
\setmonofont[Numbers=Lining]{CMU Typewriter Text Light}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Hello.\\
$1+2+2 = 5 \frac{1}{1}$\\
\texttt{Hello world}...how do you do

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you need an opentype math font for `\setmathfont`

Comment: You could do what your example tells you: Package unicode-math Warning: The first font loaded by unicode-math must be an
(unicode-math)                OpenType Math font (with script=math). If you
(unicode-math)                simply want ‘the default’ before loading
(unicode-math)                supplementary fonts over the top for certain
(unicode-math)                ranges, use: 
(unicode-math)                  \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

Comment: using the settings in that old answer [I get this with your example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG9US.png)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `CMU Typewriter Text Light` no longer works, though, and math is now upright.

Comment: the image I show above uses `....\TU/CMUTypewriterTextLight(0)/m/n/10 H` which seems OK

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmbright}       %CMU Bright for math
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{cmunb}[        %CMU Bright for text
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*mr,
    ItalicFont=*mo,
    BoldFont=*sr, % semibold
    BoldItalicFont=*so, % semibold oblique
    ]

\setmonofont[Numbers=Lining]{CMU Typewriter Text Light}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Hello. 1+2\\
$1+2+2 = 5 \frac{1}{1}$\\
\texttt{Hello world}...how do you do

\end{document}`